# in Telerik RadDropDownList popup vs dropdown

Tags: c#, telerik

I am programticly opening and closing this control so that the user has the control open if there are items in it as soon as they land in it.

I was haveing a bit of trouble with it which Telerik support cleared up.
but their solution uses a different methods than mine (not related to their solution, that was something else).

To cause the control to open I was doing this (which works):

```
 private void order_con_name_DD_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!order_con_name_DD.IsPopupVisible)
            {
                order_con_name_DD.ShowDropDown();
```

However, they are suggesting using this (which also works)

```
 private void order_con_name_DD_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!order_con_name_DD.IsPopupVisible)
        {
            RadElement element = this.order_con_name_DD.DropDownListElement.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(this.order_con_name_DD.DropDownListElement.PointFromScreen(Control.MousePosition));
            if (!(element is RadDropDownListArrowButtonElement))
            {
                this.order_con_name_DD.DropDownListElement.ArrowButton.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
```

for closing the control I was doing this (which works):

```
 private void DropDownList_PopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (order_con_name_DD.IsPopupVisible)
            {
                order_con_name_DD.CloseDropDown();
```

and their solution uses:

```
 private void DropDownList_PopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (order_con_name_DD.IsPopupVisible)
            {
                order_con_name_DD.Popup.ClosePopup(RadPopupCloseReason.Keyboard);
```

My question is (and I have researched it but not found anything so far) - what is the difference between these two working solutions?

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the `ShowDropDown` and `CloseDropDown` methods and check how they're implemented?

Comment: No, that is a couple steps above my current skill level.  If I goto the definitions  CloseDropdown states:  //     HIde the popup from the screen.  While the ClosePopUp states // Closes the IPopupControl.  Maybe there is a difference between closing and hiding something.  I have a open question with Telerik for this as well and will update with what I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...from Hristo at Telerik:

Regarding your questions:

RadDropDownList.CloseDropDown method internally calls the ClosePopup which is defined on the popup object instance.

Actually, there is not much different if you would calling the PerformClick method of the arrow button or the RadDopDownList.ShowDropDownMethod. The PerformClick method will toggle the popup state if open it will close it and vice versa.